# outputting elapsed time with powers of 10 instead of SI prefixes

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, scientific-notation, timeit

In the classroom, I often use the Python module [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to compare the execution time of code snippets. For instance, under IPython:

```
def test1(a, b):
    if a > b:
        (a, b) = (b, a)
    return (a,b)

def test2(a, b):
    (a, b) = (min(a, b), max(a,b))
    return (a,b)

%timeit test1(5, 6); test1(6, 5)
%timeit test2(5, 6); test2(6, 5)
```

Output (YMMV):

```
584 ns ± 31.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.96 µs ± 212 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The following output would make the comparison a bit easier:

```
5.84e-7 s ± 3.10e-8 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.96e-6 s ± 2.12e-7 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As of Python 3.5, there is an option `--unit` in the command line API, which accepts `sec` as a value. But measuring a multi-line statement is cumbersome. And I cannot see how to use the same parameter with the Python API, much less under IPython.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

---

EDIT: according to Matt answer, `%timeit -o` returns its result as a `TimeitResult`, which possesses the attribute I am interested in. So, a possible workaround would be:

```
timeit_result1 = %timeit -oq test1(5, 6); test1(6, 5)
print("{:.2e} sec".format(timeit_result1.best))
timeit_result2 = %timeit -oq test2(5, 6); test2(6, 5)
print("{:.2e} sec".format(timeit_result2.best))
```

Output:

```
5.34e-07 sec
1.71e-06 sec
```

NB: The intermediate assignment seems mandatory. AFAIK, `%timeit -o...` is *not* a normal expression.

Comment: `timeit.timeit()` will return results in seconds without making them _human readable_ and then you can format the output to your heart's content. The rest of the printout from the command line interface (which just calls `timeit.repeat()` and pretty-prints the results) is just visual sugar anyway as even [their own documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat) clearly warns that the output is not suitable for calculating means and std. deviation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will write my own magic command based on the `timeit` module.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `%timeit -o` option you can assign the result (a `TimeitResult` object), extract the relevant fields, and format the strings yourself,  or use in a graph. This include using `%timeit` in a loop, which can be useful to find the time complexity of a function (use `{variable}` to pass parameters). The time formatting code ipython uses is [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/cefab40bb755260ddec63efc24d8e1ea3b6fba06/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1387-L1424) in `IPython/core/magics/execution.py` if you need it.

IPython does not have a options (yet) to force a specific unit, though it could make sens to add it. Instead of writing your own magic (as you suggest in your comments), please propose a patch to IPython itself, we'll be happy to guide you through the process and review it.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question with your suggested workaround. At first glance, the source-code you refer to is a little overwhelming for me, but I will take a look.

Comment: Don't be afraid of asking for advice before contributing, we'll be happy to guide you on GitHub, and will gladely spend more time teaching someone to do it that doing it ourselve. You are also right, that `%time` are not normal expression. Use `%hist -t` to see the code after syntax transform by IPython. Everything after `%timeit` until EOL is considered a string passes down to timeit.